# TextInput focus is not a function in ios, works fine in Android

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, react-native, cross-platform

TextInput focus is not a function in ios, works fine in Android.

```
this._passcodeInput.focus()
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Which RN version?

Comment: @dv3 I'm using RN0.31

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? couldnt you achieve your desired outcome with autoFocus?

Comment: is this even supposed to work? if you want to focus a textfield you need to pass the ref like: this.refs.textinput.focus()..e.g.  
 _focusNextField(nextField) {
        this.refs[nextField].focus()
    },

Comment: @dv3 in my code _passcodeInput is assigned to this.refs.textinput. I didn't try autofocus. I'll try. I have many input fields in forms. I need to set focus to next input field on blur of previous textinput or on selection of previous radio options.

Comment: seems like you're looking for this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/ab12189f87d8e7fd84a4f1b92fa97e8894e984c7/Examples/UIExplorer/TextInputExample.android.js